# Escaping child operator in the HIVE function get_json_object

Tags: sql, json, hive, special-characters, hiveql

I have table with a string column which contains data in JSON format. Then, I'm using the function `get_json_object` to parse some data from it. The problem is that one of my fields contains a `.` in its name. So, if write the field name in plain text, the function will interpret it like a child operator.

Here is a sample code that works:

```
select get_json_object(col, '$.rootkey')
from (select '{"rootkey":15,"key.a":16,"key.b":17}' as col) test;
```

But this one fails:

```
select get_json_object(col, '$.key.a')
from (select '{"rootkey":15,"key.a":16,"key.b":17}' as col) test;
```

Is there any way escape `.` in the `get_json_object` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently get_json_object() does not support escaping, see [HIVE-2927](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2927)

The workaround is to use `lateral view json_tuple()`:

```
select v.rootkey, v.key_a, v.key_b
  from (select '{"rootkey":15,"key.a":16,"key.b":17}' as col) test
       lateral view json_tuple(col, 'rootkey', 'key.a','key.b') v as rootkey, key_a, key_b
;
```

Result:

```
v.rootkey   v.key_a   v.key_b   
15          16        17
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the discussion in jira!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, saved me a lot of time and brain cells !