# How to use impala get_json_object() when the keys contain "." in them?

Tags: hive, impala

So i have a impala table that contains data like

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|    id    |                     properties                      |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1        | {"prop1.enabled": "true", "prop2.enabled": "false"} |
| 2        | {"prop1.enabled": "true", "prop2.enabled": "true"}  |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Im trying to use `get_json_object()` in impala with a query like

```
select get_json_object(properties, '$.prop1.enabled') from mytable
```

However i get null results because in my understanding "." operator is used to parse json nodes. Is there a workaround that can be used? I tried escaping the "." using `get_json_object(properties, '$.prop1\\.enabled')` however this doesnt seem to work as well. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In Hive you can use json_tuple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68753459/2700344

Comment: Replace . With something like _ and then use get json object?